# R programming: cor.test for a data frame with only values of 0

Tags: r, correlation

I was wondering why when I run cor.test on a data frame with only values of 0 to get a correlation similarity matrix it returns NAs. The 0s in the data frame in this case represent the actual abundance of a widget based of our measurements. So I would expect that each vector that is being correlated to have a correlation estimate^2 of 1. I think I don't have a good grasp of what a correlation is and how it is implemented in cor.test. Any advice or help in understanding correlations and cor.test would be great. Code is below.

```
corpij <- function(i,j,data) {(cor.test(data[,i],data[,j])$estimate)^2}
corp <- Vectorize(corpij, vectorize.args=list("i","j"))
r2_scores <- outer(1:n,1:n,corp,ready_cor)
```

Best

Comment: Take look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence You can't have a standard deviation of 0 (see denominator)

Comment: That makes sense. Can't divide by 0... Thanks so much. @Vlo